# Where are WhatsApp voice notes stored on an Android device?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have checked the /WhatsApp folder (and all the subfolders under it) but they are not there. I also tried the /Android folder but I am not able to find an entry for WhatsApp there.

I am using a Nexus 5, if that is important.

Comment: Have you checked `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/` ?

Comment: @MinNaingOo: I checked. That folder contains audio files that have been sent as attachments not the voice notes sent by pressing and holding the mic button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your voice files are also stored in the whatsapp folder.

The path is:

1. For voice notes:

   `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes/`

   The file names are starting with PTT. The files are stored here if the sender recorded the note via whatsapp.
2. For audio:

   `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/`

   The files are stored here if the sender recorded the note in an external application and shared it to whatsapp

Comment: Well what do you know... It IS there. I could have sworn I didnt see it the last time i checked. Thanks.

Comment: For people who couldn't find this folder: Some (most?) phones have an SD card folder; the above folder will be inside that.

Comment: That is the path for it, but sometimes you won't find them there, so a workarround if you want to have it in your computer is to select it, click share, and send it to your email address. The only problem is that you must do it one by one :(